# Ubuntu distributed JDK and TCK

Tags: server, java, openjdk

I searched quite a bit to find out if there are any online documents related to this. All I could find was RedHat/CentOS OpenJDK binaries were tested against TCK and explained here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013

I was wondering if the OpenJDK distributed from Ubuntu LTS/update repositories is also TCK certified? Is there any official pages showing this without a doubt?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the license: https://openjdk.java.net/legal/OCTLA-JDK9+.pdf   Canonical is on the signature list https://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/jck-access.html And to top it off: we use Iced Tea. That package maintained by Redhat.

Comment: That page only lists organizations which were granted access to `JCK`. That is not a proof that the build passed all the JCK/TCK tests. I don't quite understand what using IcedTea has anything to do with this as long as canonical/ubuntu was compiling from sources. The resulting binaries would need to be tested. Isnt it?

Comment: \It lists organizations that signed "the OCTLA TCK agreement" . And I doubt there is ANY openjdk that passed TCK. None of them have "Java SE" named with the package or in the package name. Redhat tested against TCK but ... the results are nowhere to be found.

Comment: I dont see why there would be results, they release binaries which pass the test. It is the result. For example see this: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk
It is also explained in this RedHat blog entry too
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/05/migrating-from-oracle-jdk-to-openjdk-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-what-you-need-to-know/